# Mysql not starting on XAMPP - Windows 8.1

Tags: mysql, xampp

I installed XAMPP on my PC and when I am starting MySQL a message is showing 
`Attempting to start MySQL service...`. I have tried changing port, reinstalled but nothing is happening. Previously I have installed winmysqladmin, MAMP, WAMP but now I have uninstalled. So for that MySQL is not starting ?

Is there any solution for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Very first thing to check is the windows firewall. Another thing is try to start it and go to the windows event logs and see if there are any log related to mysql (if it has you can search by the error).

Comment: Also, check if you installed it with administrator privileges. Another thing is don't install it on the program files/program files x86 folders

Comment: Try: right click > start as administrator. But instead of XAMPP I recommend using a Vagrant image for a local LAMP setup.

Comment: When i run XAMPP as administrator there is a option "Service Is Installed as Windows Service". Done!! . Thanks @CrouchingKitten